# MYSQL query is not running in mysql workbench while inserting data through loop

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Error :  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 0.000 sec

code :

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 4;
    WHILE v1 <= 94 DO
        INSERT INTO `ostopd`.`identificationmandatorycheck`
(`Id`,
`UserId`,
`voterId`,
`passport`,
`CreatedOn`,
`CreatedBy`,
`UpdatedOn`,
`UpdatedBy`,
`Active`,
`Deleted`)
VALUES
(v1,v1,'O','O',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,v1,NULL,NULL,0b1,0b0);
        SET v1 = v1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
```

Table Schema

Id bigint(20) AI PK 
UserId bigint(20) 
voterId varchar(1) 
passport varchar(1) 
CreatedOn timestamp 
CreatedBy bigint(20) 
UpdatedOn timestamp 
UpdatedBy bigint(20) 
Active bit(1) 
Deleted bit(1)

Full Error Response
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: show also the part of the message after  near  .. is the most important part ..

Comment: which line is the line 3?

Comment: The definition of the procedure is fine -- you get the error when you try to _run_ it, correct?  Like @scaisEdge said, it would be really helpful to have the rest of the error message.  Since you tagged this with `mysql-workbench`, you should be able to select the line with the error in the Output pane and then right click it and choose "Copy Response" to paste it here.  It might also be helpful to show us the create statement for the `identificationmandatorycheck` table (right click the table in the Navigator pane and choose Copy To Clipboard -> Create Statement).

Comment: Look up DELIMITER

Comment: Table Schema

Id bigint(20) AI PK 
UserId bigint(20) 
voterId varchar(1) 
passport varchar(1) 
CreatedOn timestamp 
CreatedBy bigint(20) 
UpdatedOn timestamp 
UpdatedBy bigint(20) 
Active bit(1) 
Deleted bit(1)


Full Error Response
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: I did It n thanks @RiggsFolly for pointing it out for Delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
 drop procedure if exists my_proc11;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc11()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 INT;
    SET v1 = 1;
    WHILE v1 <= 94 DO
        INSERT INTO `ostopd`.`educationmandatorycheck`
(`UserId`,
`degree`,
`marksheet`,
`collegeId`,
`CreatedOn`,
`CreatedBy`,
`UpdatedOn`,
`UpdatedBy`,
`Active`,
`Deleted`)
VALUES
(v1,'M','M','O',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,v1,NULL,NULL,0b1,0b0);
        SET v1 = v1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

call myproc11();
```